# How to find out sizes of sections in NASM?

Tags: linux, nasm

I am writing program in NASM using bin output format. I am creating ELF headers manually. I need to know start address and length of every section.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by defining sections order

```
SECTION .header   progbits
SECTION .text     progbits  follows=.header   align=16
SECTION .rodata   progbits  follows=.text     align=16
SECTION .data     progbits  follows=.rodata   align=16
SECTION .bss      nobits    follows=.data     align=16
```

and adding these lines in the end of file:

```
section .header
  header_start  equ  $$
  header_length  equ  $-$$

section .text
  text_start  equ  $$
  text_length  equ  $-$$

section .rodata
  rodata_start  equ  $$
  rodata_length  equ  $-$$

section .data
  data_start  equ  $$
  data_length  equ  $-$$

section .bss
  bss_start  equ  $$
  bss_length  equ  $-$$
```